# what mean by this parameters in euclidean hash family?

Tags: java, data-structures

in euclidean hash family library in java i do not understand  parameters `w` and if there is relation between choice the value of `w` and value of `dimension`.

```
public EuclidianHashFamily(int w,int dimensions){
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
        this.w=w;
```

i want to know what mean by this integers to know what values assign to it.

```
public EuclideanHash(int dimensions,int w){
        Random rand = new Random();
        this.w = w;
        this.offset = rand.nextInt(w);

        randomProjection = new Vector(dimensions);
        for(int d=0; d<dimensions; d++) {
            //mean 0
            //standard deviation 1.0
            double val = rand.nextGaussian();
            randomProjection.set(d, val);
```

Comment: what jar does `EuclidianHashFamily` come from? Any javadocs?

Comment: It is being used for Random.nextInt so see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of web search leading to me quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing#LSH_algorithm_for_nearest_neighbor_search):

> One of the main applications of LSH is to provide a method for efficient approximate [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) algorithms. Consider an LSH family . The algorithm has **two main parameters: the width parameter `k` and the number of hash tables `L`**.

So, `w` is the **width**.